# I stuck when install Apache Maven in my Windows PC

Tags: windows, maven

I am not able to install maven on my 32 bit windows.I followed assistance on internet but still it is not working.

> error :C:\Users\LAXMON>mvn -version 'mvn' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I also get below when i do echo

PATH was C:=======

> \ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%
>
> \System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\C:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library";C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files
>
> \MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities

1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\

JAVA_HOME:========

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40

MAVEN_HOME=======

> C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9
>
> C:\Users\LAXMON>echo $MAVEN_HOME%
>
> $MAVEN_HOME%

Not sure where i am going wrong.

Comment: You need to add the folder that the mvn executable is in onto the system path, and *then open a new command window*.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28545224/1254208 - Adding it to the system path won't update any already open cmd windows.  Also the syntax for echo command should be echo %MAVEN_HOME% - Windows doesn't use the $ sign.

Comment: It worked when i opened a new command window. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is offical tutorial from Apache Maven homepage: https://maven.apache.org/install.html

It will help you install Maven correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps to configure maven on windows machine :

- **Download maven binary** (apache-maven-X.X.X-bin.zip)  from http://maven.apache.org/download.html and extract the zip file to a folder say `D:\maven3`
- **Configure environment variables** (The installation directories of JDK and Maven might differ in your case.)

  JAVA_HOME  >> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\`

  MAVEN_HOME >> `D:\maven3\`
- **Add Paths**

  %MAVEN_HOME%\bin ; %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
- **Verify :** To verify it, in command prompt, type “`mvn –version`” to verify the installation detail.

Source : http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2012/01/configure-maven-project-in-eclipse.html